# How to add trailing spaces to a decimal value that varies in length?

Tags: sql

I have an `amount` column that is of type `decimal(18,2)`, and I want to have data in my output as `decimal(15,2)` with varying spaces.

For example, I have a value of `45.01` in my table, I want the output to be `45.01XXXXXXXXXXX`.

How should I format my column while reading the table?

Another example would be: `7368.09` should appear as `7368.09XXXXXXXXX`.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select cast(val as char(15))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server, you can use the following:

```
DECLARE @input DECIMAL(18,9) = 7368.09
SELECT CAST(CAST(@input as DECIMAL(15,2)) AS VARCHAR) + REPLICATE(' ', 100)
```

The above query will add 100 spaces after the number

Note:If you need varying spaces, you need to define your criteria that will help determine "n" which you can use in the REPLICATE function above